# Please explain chess Notation?

Tags: notation, game-complexity

Although I love chess, I don't understand how to describe the positions on the board and moves of the chess pieces using numbers and letters. I tried to understand it by myself in hopes to answer an unanswered question (and apparently complex). I couldn't be of any help because I got lost when the question involved chess notation. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Should I call it "Chess Jargon" instead?

Comment: The correct term is "chess notation".

Comment: If you want to talk abut chess you have to take the time to understand the language.